# Group the keys of a keyValueGroupDataset based in a specific rule in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I need your help being a beginner.

I have a `KeyValueGroupedDataset[String, some_complex_data]`.
Let's say the keys are:

| key | some_complex_data |
| --- | --- |
| A_1_Z | collection of something |
| B_1_Z | collection of something |
| A_2_X | collection of something |
| B_2_X | collection of something |
| A_3_Y | collection of something |

I also have another information, for now in a Dataframe, that A and B should be grouped together, but only if the rest of the string match.

For example `A_1_Z` and `B_1_Z` together in one single group, and `A_2_X` with `B_2_X`, but `A_3_Y` has no match, so there is no grouping for it. And of course the purpose is to aggregate all the collection of something all together.

| key | some_complex_data |
| --- | --- |
| A_1_Z, B_1_Z | collection of something |
| A_2_X, B_2_X | collection of something |
| A_3_Y | collection of something |

Is there a way to group - aggregate already a `KeyValueGroupedDataset`, or what other strategy can be used to do this grouping?

Comment: Welcome to SO. What did you try so far?

Comment: Thank you. I managed to combine the rule "A-B should be group together", when it matches the rest of the string. 
So, now i have an : array<struct<keyO:string,keyN:string>>, where the full comparison is done (A_1_Z, B_1_Z). But still don't know how to modify the keyValueGroupDataset based on this.